# Why can I access this private member from an other object?

Tags: c++, member

I am currently learning C++ from Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice and there is an example I cannot really understand. There is a class called Link which looks like this.

```
class Link{

public:

    Link(Link* p=nullptr, Link* n=nullptr, const std::string& label);
    Link* erase();

private:
    std::string label;
    Link* succ;
    Link* prev;

};


Link* Link::erase() {

    if (this ==  nullptr) return nullptr;

    if(prev) prev->succ = succ;
    if(succ) succ->prev = prev;

    return succ;


}
```

What I do not understand is why 
`prev->succ = succ;` is correct since I am assigning to a private member of an object from an other object. What am I missing here?

Comment: Because you're within the same class. Private variables are accessible to the class itself, don't think of them as separate objects at that level.

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244818/why-can-private-member-variable-be-changed-by-class-instance). It's for C# but same concept for C++

Comment: Aside: the check `if (this ==  nullptr)` is strictly unnecessary. `this` can never be equal to `nullptr` in a well-formed program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access is per class not per object. Many things would not work as they do if access would be per instance. For example this type

```
class foo {
    int x;
};
```

Has a compiler generated copy constructor which is something like this:

```
foo::foo(const foo& other) {
    x = other.x;
}
```

Access restictions are for encapsulation and encapsulation is to make sure that the class invariants are not violated. However, typically invarants are violated temporarily inside methods. For example consider this class

```
class Sum {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int sum = 0;
public:
    void set(int x,int y);
    int get_sum() { return sum; }
};
```

The invariant here is that `sum` is always the sum of `a` and `b`. However, inside the `set` method...

```
void Sum::set(int x,int y) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
    sum = a + b;
}
```

This invariant is only restored on the very last line. It is your responsibility to restore the invariant such that from outside view it always holds.

Further, access restriction is to hide implementation details. In the `Sum` example, the user has no knowledge that the member `sum` exists and they need not know about it. However, the definition of the class methods are dealnig with implementation details. Dealing with implementation details of a different object makes no difference, because they are the same.

What is the relation to your example?

The purpose of access restrictions is to allow you to make sure from outside invariants are never violated and to hide implementation details. Inside a method of `Link` you have to know what you are doing. You have to know what is the meaning of `prev` and `succ`, wether its the members of `this` or another object. The method has to make sure that the invariants are not violated: After calling `erase` the caller still has a valid `Link`. And to do that you are dealing with implementation details: a valid `Link` has `prec` and a `succ`.

Conclusion: Not being able to access private methods of other objects would be a major hurdle and not really bring an advantage (because anyhow while inside a method you are already dealing with implementation details of the class and you often do violate invariants temporarily).

Comment: "typically invarants are violated inside methods" *temporarily violated*

Answer (score 2):

Access restrictions apply to *names*, not objects.

From [`[class.access]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access):

> A member of a class can be
>
> - private; that is, **its name** can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.
> - protected; that is, **its name** can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared, by classes derived from
>     that class, and by their friends (see [class.protected]).
> - public; that is, **its name** can be used anywhere without access restriction.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

Because private members are private to the **class**, not just the **instance**.

Thus **all** instances of `Link` can see each other’s private members, not just their own.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask yourself a question, how do copy constructors work.

encapsulation is for classes, not objects.

encapsulation is a way to "hide" the code to outside the class. In the class, every private field and function can be accessed. It's not a way to protect the objects, it's a way to hide implementations which users of the class don't need to know the them to improve developing effeciency.